# Android Element view

Tags: java, android

I have a button that creates an EditText, now I have a button that deletes the last element, but if I click it 2 times, I get an error because when I "spawn" an EditText I create a View:

code

```
vista = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edit, null);
```

When I go to delete it (so I delete 1 EditText) this view will be deleted too, but if I press the button once, I get error (don't remember which).

so i create an ArrayList that contains all the view spawned (every time i press the button for add them) and all do right, but when i have to remove EditText i remove Element by ArrayList but in app EditText will not be removed.

any suggestion?

Comment: add your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you the answer from what i have understood from your explanation. If I have not clear with what you needed. please do clarify so, that I can help you.

You are creating `EditText` dynamically and adding to the parent Layout.

```
parentView.addView(edittextObject);
```

Adding a `edittext` is working good. but, removing of `edittext` is not performing.

If this is your question.

Remove the selected edittext by clicking on delete button listener.

```
parentLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
```

This single line of code will remove `edittext` from parent layout.